# Ubuntu machine with RNDIS tethered phone can not receive packets from internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I tried to tether my old Windows Mobile 6 phone with my Ubuntu computer to use the phone's network.
However, even though the kernel seems to recognize the phone and it is used as a network device I can not receive any packets from http-requests.

The following output is from dmesg:

```
[  230.884554] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0: dev can't take 1558 byte packets (max 1536), adjusting MTU to 1478
[  230.892791] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0: RNDIS_MSG_QUERY(0x00010202) failed, -47
[  230.910356] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0: eth1: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1, RNDIS device, 80:00:60:0f:e8:00
[  230.910382] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[  241.853911] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

So, the phone is recognized as eth1:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:00:60:0f:e8:00  
      inet addr:192.168.0.57  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::8200:60ff:fe0f:e800/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1478  Metric:1
      RX packets:953 errors:759 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:197786 (197.7 KB)  TX bytes:224916 (224.9 KB)
```

And pinging an internet address works as well:

```
PING www.l.google.com (173.194.69.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bk-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.69.105): icmp_req=1 ttl=40 time=299 ms
64 bytes from bk-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.69.105): icmp_req=2 ttl=40 time=117 ms
64 bytes from bk-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.69.105): icmp_req=3 ttl=40 time=136 ms
64 bytes from bk-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.69.105): icmp_req=4 ttl=40 time=135 ms
64 bytes from bk-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.69.105): icmp_req=5 ttl=40 time=344 ms
64 bytes from bk-in-f105.1e100.net (173.194.69.105): icmp_req=6 ttl=40 time=103 ms

--- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 103.563/189.388/344.436/95.197 ms
```

But when I try to retrieve a web page it does not work (as an example the output of a wget request):

```
% wget www.google.com
--2012-01-16 18:59:12--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 173.194.69.105, 173.194.69.106, 173.194.69.147, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|173.194.69.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.google.de/ [following]
--2012-01-16 18:59:12--  http://www.google.de/
Resolving www.google.de... 173.194.69.94
Connecting to www.google.de|173.194.69.94|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ^C
```

So I am really surprised why this does not work an hope someone here has an idea how I could get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after fiddeling around for a little more it turned out that the problem was the MTU size - setting it to something lower than 1100 bytes did the trick and the connection works pretty much flawless now.